# Objective C in Windows

Tags: objective-c, windows

Pardon me for this silly question. I would like to know is there any possibility to run the following program in windows

```
 #import<Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc,const char* argv[]) { 

NSAutoReleasePool *pool =[[NSAutoReleasePool  alloc]init];

NSLog(@"Hello World")

[pool drain];

 }
```

I know there are objective c compilers available for windows but I want to know is there anything support The `<Foundation/Foundation.h>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  One possibility is to compile it with GCC using the [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/) framework.